# Subdirectories in Content directory in XNA Project, is it possible?

Tags: c#, xna

I have many files in my Content directory in my GameProject in XNA. I would like to clear the mess and put them into subdirectories. But when I've done I have an Error when try to LoadContent. My catalog-structure is like this:

```
Content
|+Ships
||-1.png
||-2.png
||-3.png
||-4.png
||-5.png
|-1-player.png
|-...
```

When I try to load:

```
Texture2D ship1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("1");
```

it returns me an error

> "An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

---

So, is there any solution to have many subdirectories in Content directory?

P.S:
I have correct name of assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your diagram right, you want to import a file named "1-player.png". Why don't you use

```
Texture2D ship1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("1-player");
```

then?
And of course, you can have subdirectories for your `ContentManager`. Simply define the path

```
Texture2D item = Conten.Load<Texture2D>(@"Path\To\Your\Item.png");
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197848.aspx) and especially the remarks for the parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have put: "ships/1"